# Add SVN to existing XAMPP installation

Tags: svn, xampp

I used an old [guide](http://serk01.wordpress.com/2008/09/21/how-to-create-your-own-home-svn-repository-with-xamppapache/) (from 2008) to try to install the SVN modules into the existing apache server that comes with XAMPP. When I try to start apache it gives an error that it can't load the dav_svn module because the procedure was not found.

My guess is that the latest version of SVN is not compatible with the apache version shipped with XAMPP. Does anyone have a guide to get this working correctly?

Answer (score 1):

you must upgrade your **Apache version shipped with XAMPP** else you have to use lesser version of SVN i.e. you must use svn's version which released at the time of your XAMPP's Apache version released.

this will defiantly solve your problem though you can use

1. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18106/Subversion-TortoiseSVN-Installed-and-started-on-Wi
2. http://svn-ref.assembla.com/subversion-server-guide-windows.html

Comment: Neither of these links are using XAMPP. I'm sorry but this does not help.